# Prove that minimally 2-connected graphs have a vertex of order 2?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, graph-connectivity

I need help proving that every minimally 2-connected graph has a vertex of order 2 (the order of a vertex being equal to the number of edges that "enters" it).

> By definition, a graph is **2-connected**, if for every vertex $x, x
> \in V(G), G- x$ is connected.

Minimally 2-connected graphs have the property that they are 2-connected graphs but when an edge is removed from them, they become 1-connected graphs.

I've seen from other posts that if I can show that all minimally 2-connected graphs can be formed by adding paths between vertices of a cycle graph, then I should have my answer.

However, I am not sure how to show this. Is this also even the right approach?

Many thanks

Comment: If you have a minimally 2 connected graph $G=(V,E)$ you can find a vertices $v,u$ such that deleting one edge would make the edge $vu$ a bridge. If you delete this edge also you get 2 components. But this components must be minimally 2 connected themselves. This would give us an idea for an recursive proof. We do the same again in one of the components over and over, until one of the components in use only contains 1 vertex. This vertex has degree 2.

Comment: I don't know exactly if your mentioned approach would work also. I hope my idea was helpful and I didn't miss any detail.

Comment: @includeCMath, thanks for the answer. How do we know that the 2 components must be  minimally connected themselves?

Comment: Assume they are 2 connceted but not minimally 2-connected than there would be an edge we could delete and the component is still 2-connected, this edge would have been in $G$ already, hence $G$ wasn't minimally. If we not 2 connected at all, this component must include a bridge, and again this bridge would have already been in $G$, hence $G$ wasn't 2-connected at all.

Comment: @includeCMath  ah thank you, I understand that part now. However I still don't understand what the use of the recursion is. If we can keep splitting G into minimally 2 connected graphs we eventually end up with one of the components being just an isolate vertex. Why does this mean that the vertex has degree 2?

Comment: Because deleting 2 edges between the 2 components disconnects them, so there are exactly two edged between that one vertex (which forms a component on its own) and the other component, hence both edges are incident to said vertex and that are the only ones.

Comment: @includeCMath sorry im still a bit lost. i dont understand how cutting to edges helps or why we are allowed to do that. doesn't minimally 2-connected graph mean a graph that is 2-connected (ie removing 2 or more vertices will make it disconnected) such that when we remove an edge, the remaining graph is 1-connected (ie removing 1 vertex will make it disconnected)?

Comment: I just went over it carefully and I think I found a mistake in my approach.. since a cycle is a minimally two connected graph (deleting any two edges would disconnect it) we can not assume that the two parts are minimally 2-connected again. Sorry for my mistkae, I should have checked the details properly before posting it  ._.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you mention is close to the ear-decomposition of 2-connected graphs: the edge set of any 2-connected graph can be partitioned into $C_0, P_1, \ldots, P_k$ where $C_0$ is a cycle, $P_1$ is a path between distinct nodes of $C_0$, $P_i$ is a path between distinct nodes of $C_0 \cup P_1 \cup \ldots \cup P_{i-1}$. However notice that the paths (except $P_1$) are not forced to have their endpoints in $C_0$. Also, one can easily show that if a graph has an ear decomposition, it is 2-connected.

Given $G$ a minimally 2-connected graph, we want to prove that there is an ear decomposition of $G$ where the last path $P_k$ has length at least $2$. Indeed any inner vertex of $P_k$ has degree 2 in $G$, so it is sufficient to prove that there is at least one inner vertex. Take any ear decomposition $C_0 \cup \ldots \cup P_k$ of $G$. If $P_k$ is a single edge $e$, then $G \setminus \{e\} = C_0 \cup P_1 \cup \ldots \cup P_{k-1}$ has an ear-decomposition, hence it is 2-connected. This contradicts the fact $G$ is minimally 2-connected. Hence $P_k$ has at least one inner node.

Here is another proof that does not use ear-decomposition:

Take a cut $\delta(S)$ with a shore $S \subseteq V$ such that $d(S) = 2$ and $|S|$ is minimum, and show that $|S| = 1$.

Suppose that there is an edge $uv \in E[S]$. By minimality of $G$, there is a cut $S'$ with $uv \in \delta(S')$ and $d(S') = 2$. By minimality of $|S|$, $S' \nsubseteq S$. By submodularity of the cut function,
$$ 4 = d(S) + d(S') \geq d(S \cup S') + d(S \cap S') \geq 4$$
where the last inequality comes from the fact that each cut has cardinal at least 2. We deduce that all the inequalities must be tight, hence $d(S \cup S') = d(S \cap S') = 2$. But $|S \cap S'| < |S|$ (as either $u$ or $v$ is not in $S'$), contradicting the minimality of $|S|$.

Comment: Shore is just another name for the side of a cut (defining a cut $X$ has an edge set, a shore $U$ is a vertex set with $X = \delta^+(U)$). By minimality of $G$, I mean the assumption that $G$ is minimally 2-connected. I do not use an undefined notion of minimality. I rewrite to make it clearer.

Comment: Ignore this, I understand what you are saying, that works perfectly, thank you so much!!